# Visual team service plugin in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I installed `Visual Studio team services` plugin in Android studio. when I want to connect to MY tfs 2015, it connects successfully, but when I want to push My project to that repository it failed with this error:

"RPC failed; HTTP 401, curl 22, the requested URL returned error:401"

My url in config is like this : 
`http://userName:Pass@TFSURL/ProjectName/_git/MyRepo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to IIS Manager, select Team Foundation Server and then the tfs node under Team Foundation Server. In the right panel I selected authentication and disabled `digest authentication`. then I restarted My IIS. My problem solved.

anyone knows how to use `digest authentication` enabled, and connect to tfs via `Visual Studio team services` plugin in Android studio? because I don't want to change IIS setting.